# How to downgrade Perl on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, perl, osx-mavericks, perl-module

The newly release Mavericks has removed the deprecated module "Switch.pm" from its repository. 
However, I have recently try to build AOSP source tree and it somehow uses this module to generate "make-hash-tools.pl"

The Mavericks has perl version of 5.16.2, and its predecessor Mountain Lion has a 5.12.4. Is there a way to downgrade my Perl?

Compilation error looks like this:

```
  Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-\ 
  multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level\
  /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2\
  /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16\
  /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level \
  /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at external/webkit/Source/WebCore\
  /make-hash-tools.pl line 23.
```

Thanks~!

Comment: Alternatively install Switch.pm from CPAN.

Comment: Downgrading the system perl would not be a good idea. You'll break everything else that relies on it. Just install `Switch` from CPAN, as @SlavenRezic says. Or use perlbrew to build a local perl.

Comment: i tried to install Switch using CPANM, but it says Switch can not be found!

Comment: @FangBoy Please show the exact command you used  and the build log from the failed cpanm installation –  `cpanm Switch` ought to work.

Comment: $sudo cpanm Switch --force
--> Working on Switch
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RG/RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Switch-2.16 ... OK
Building and testing Switch-2.16 ... FAIL
! Testing Switch-2.16 failed but installing it anyway.
Successfully installed Switch-2.16
1 distribution installed

Comment: Is this ok? I forced to install Switch.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19608799/edit) your question to include the output rather than posting it into multiple columns. Forcing a broken module to install is a *bad idea*, as it is likely useless. Interestingly, I have the same test failures (2-3) with perl 5.18.1 on Linux, which suggests that module is broken. The latest version that installs for me is 2.06. **Edit**: There are already [*lots* of bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Switch) about test failures, we are not the first… ⇒ Port your code

Comment: Thanks, It seems that I forced installation and fix the compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like running `sudo cpanm Switch --force` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

You can use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to install a parallel version of Perl in its own directory with its own modules. Currently it lets you install Perl as far back as 5.003_07, although not all of them are supported by Perl Porters for security fixes.

It would probably be simpler to [install Switch from CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) though.

Comment: Could you give me a step by step commands? I tried CPAN, but it says module Switch cannot be found. Thanks

Comment: `cpan Switch` installed it fine for me.

Comment: ~$ cpan Switch
Reading '/Users/USER_NAME/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Sat, 26 Oct 2013 14:53:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Switch'
Cannot create directory /Users/USER_NAME/.cpan/prefs

Comment: What user are you running cpan as? What use owns `/Users/USER_NAME/.cpan`?

Comment: Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/given.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 293 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  2-3
Files=3, Tests=590,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.01 sys +  0.40 cusr  0.02 csys =  0.50 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/3 test programs. 2/590 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
  /usr/local/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports RGARCIA/Switch-2.16.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force

Comment: I used sudo cpan Switch to install cpan, then I ran cpan Switch and I received the Test Summary Report as above. Why would it failed the make install?

Comment: There's a bug report with a patch which is probably related to the test failure: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=60380

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this:

```
$ sudo defaults write '/Library/Preferences/com.apple.versioner.perl' Version 5.12
```

It makes perl run version 12 for most stuff. Unfortunately, not for `apache` ...

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on 10.9.2, with no "force".

---

```
cpan[2]> install Switch
Running install for module 'Switch'
Running make for C/CH/CHORNY/Switch-2.17.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
```

... bunch of fetch stuff ...

```
CPAN.pm: Building C/CH/CHORNY/Switch-2.17.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Switch
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

... a bunch of xcode license stuff ...

```
cp Switch.pm blib/lib/Switch.pm
Manifying blib/man3/Switch.3pm
  CHORNY/Switch-2.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/given.t ... ok       
t/nested.t .. ok   
t/switch.t .. ok       
All tests successful.
Files=3, Tests=590,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.22 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.28 CPU)
Result: PASS
  CHORNY/Switch-2.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Installing /Library/Perl/5.16/Switch.pm
Installing /usr/local/share/man/man3/Switch.3pm
Appending installation info to /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/perllocal.pod
  CHORNY/Switch-2.17.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

---

I then ran my code that previously pitched the "Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC" error, and the code ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find these command works.

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell

cpan > force install Switch
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another command :

```
sudo cpan -f Switch
```

I had to execute the command 2 times but for me it works on Yosemite. Thank s this [blog](http://blog.khairulazam.net/2014/01/30/mac-os-x-cant-locate-switch-perl/).